# Secure Polygons

Tags: dynamical-systems, billiards

The secure-square problem is this:

> Suppose you have a square with mirror edges.
> In these square, you choose two points, one as a light source and the other as a target.
> On these square, you can place light-blocking points.
> The square is called *secure,* if every ray of light from the source to the target will hit a light-blocking point.

There is a [nice solution](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/is-the-square-a-secure-polygon) which states that 16 points are enough to make a square secure.

Can this be extended to triangles, pentagons and other polygons? Are there references on this subject?

Comment: My guess is that's possible to extend the same logic to equilateral triangles and regular hexagons, since you can create a lattice that completely covers the plane just by symmetry operations.

Comment: Please write out the definition of "secure" instead of requiring users to chase it offsite.

Comment: Well, that's better, but "where all this [sic] concepts are as in the illumination problems" fails to illuminate the concepts. The more self-contained a question is, the more likely it is that someone will answer it.